# Control action method by GET or POST in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm new to Struts2, coming from a PHP background, where I'd often have the same file handling GET and POST requests, and processing a form if the request is a POST request.

I currently have the following in struts.xml:

```
<action name="ProcessData" class="ProcessDataAction">
    <result name="*">processdata.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="ProcessDataUpload" class="ProcessDataAction" method="upload">
    <result name="*">processsdata.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Which works fine, but it bothers me that the URL that handles POST is different, since now if the user reloads the page, they get an error rather than simply seeing the contents of the GET page.

So my question is, is there any way to tell struts2 to call one method if it's a GET request, and another method if it's a POST request?

Comment: you have to use req.getMethod() in your Action class to distinguish between GET and POST and put your logic accordingly.

Comment: @Reddy: Putting such logic in the action class doesn't scale, since you need to then duplicate the logic across all actions you want the behavior for. This is more a job for an interceptor, or perhaps an action mapper.

Comment: When a page sends data to an action why care if it comes from post or get? You can of course put many actions in one file, but why one would want or one for GET and another for POST is baffling.

Comment: GET and POST are intended to have different purposes, so it is actually useful to be able to restrict certain requests to one or the other. Servlets allow this easily, as does JAX-RS.

Comment: Agreed Steven, that's where I'm coming from.  I want to process data when I see a POST request, and not when I see a GET.  Seems to me this isn't the way it's done in struts2, so I'm doing it the suggested way, but I'm surprised there's no easy distinction.  I was expecting there would be some simple way to say `request="post"` or something similar in struts.xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Struts2 doesn't offer what you described out of the box. If you want to enforce that a particular action method is invokable only by certain HTTP methods, then you'd need to create a custom interceptor and probably a few custom annotations.

If you just want the same action to handle displaying the form and processing it, then you can do the following:

```
public class MyAction {
  public String execute() {
    return INPUT;
  }

  public void validate() {
    // perform any form validation needed
  }

  public String submit() {
    // process the form and then redirect
  }
}
```

In your form, you would submit to ProcessData!submit. The ! separates the action from the action method name. It provides what you have already, but you don't need to explicitly map each method in the struts.xml.

> But it bothers me that the URL that handles POST is different, since now if the user reloads the page, they get an error rather than simply seeing the contents of the GET page.

Redirecting the user after a successful post completely nullifies this point. Look at the "Redirect After Post" or "Post/Redirect/Get" pattern).

Answer (score 2):

Not by default, no. IMO the cleanest solution is to tweak the method name via an interceptor that looks at the request type. For example, I had a simple one that looked for executeGet and executePost methods.

Whether or not it's a great idea... different issue.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that implementation?  And why do you think it's not a good idea?

Comment: There's not too much to elaborate on, IIRC. The ActionInvocation has an ActionProxy, the ActionProxy has a methodName attribute. I think I just changed it (I could be 100% mis-remembering) based on the request type... I'd have to dig. I'm not saying it's a good or bad idea, I'm just not convinced it's important.